# R-code in Slurm cluster not read properly

Tags: r, syntax-error, slurm

I'm running an R-code on a Slurm Cluster with the following ".sh" file:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --partition=p_parallel
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=16
#SBATCH --workdir=/work/uder2/ODE/lancio/
module load statistics/r-3.6.1
srun Rscript   TEST.R
```

The R-code is quite simple. Sometimes like

```
DIRbase     = "/work/uder2/ODE/"
DIRdata     = paste(DIRbase,"data/",sep="")
list.files(DIRdata)
load(paste(DIRdata,"Data.Rdata",sep=""))


NAME = "PriorU" 
ialg = 3

nG  = 500  
LimEta = 40  

LimMu2  = 15 
LimMin = 500

LimMu = 0.1
LimSpike = 10
LimSigma2 = (8)^2/(-2*log(LimMu))*1.2


NAME = paste(NAME,"_ng",nG, sep="")

### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### 
### MODELS
### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### 

DATA = allGenesData
nrowData = nrow(DATA$premature)


sd1 = as.numeric(apply(DATA$premature,1,var))
sd2 = as.numeric(apply(DATA$mature,1,var))
sd3 = as.numeric(apply(DATA$nascent,1,var))

epsi = 0.000001
App = c(which(sd1<=epsi),which(sd2<=epsi),which(sd3<=epsi))
App2 = c(which(sd1>50),which(sd2>100000),which(sd3>1500))

minep = 0.1
xy1 = as.numeric(apply(DATA$premature,1,min))
xy2 = as.numeric(apply(DATA$mature,1,min))
xy3 = as.numeric(apply(DATA$nascent,1,min))
App3 = c(which(xy1<=minep),which(xy2<=minep),which(xy3<=minep))
```

In actuality, the code is much longer, but I don't think the content of the file is important.

What is happening is that, sometimes, the code is  not written properly. For example, instead of

```
App3 = c(which(xy1<=minep),which(xy2<=minep),which(xy3<=minep))
```

is read

```
App3  which(xy1<=minep),which(xy2<=minep),which(xy3<=minep))
```

Then, without touching the code and launching again the ".sh" file, the code is read properly.
This happens "randomly", and never in the same section of the code.

It seems it is related to the code length.

Any help?

Thanks

EDIT 1:

As an example, the output of a slurm file is

```
[1] "Data.Rdata"
Loading required package: MASS
##
## Markov Chain Monte Carlo Package (MCMCpack)
## Copyright (C) 2003-2020 Andrew D. Martin, Kevin M. Quinn, and Jong Hee Park
##
## Support provided by the U.S. National Science Foundation
## (Grants SES-0350646 and SES-0350613)
##
Loading required package: stats4
null device 
          1 
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"      Beta0   = rep(-4,3),
      Betagonale Psi"
Execution halted
srun: error: node02: task 0: Exited with exit code 1
```

and the code is

```
priors  = list(
     Beta0 = list(
         type        = "Normal",
         Par1        = rep(-4,3),
         Par2        = rep(10,3)
       ),
       Beta1 = list(
         type        = "Normal",
         Par1        = rep(1.8,3), 
         Par2        = rep(10,3)
       ),
      VarK   = list(
        type        = "TruncatedNormal",
        Par1        = rep(0,3),
        Par2        = rep(100,3),
        Par3        = rep(0.0000000,3),
        Par4        = rep(LimSigma2,3), 
        Par5        = rep(2,3)
        #Par5        = rep(2,3)
      ), 
      RegCoef = list(
          type        = "Normal",
          Par1        = c(0,0,0,0,0), ## (1 o stessa dimension)
          Par2        = rep(100,5)
      ),
      sigmaMat = list(
          type        = "InverseWishart",
          Par1        = rep(10,3), 
          Par2        = c(diag(1,5)) ## diagonale Psi
      ),

      DPpar = list(
          type        = "Gamma",
          Par1        = 1, 
          Par2        = 1 ## diagonale Psi
      )
    )
```

Comment: This sounds impossible. Do you have an example of the type of `slurm*.out` files that are being generated. I am willing to bet it has something to do with environment variables. To ensure that `TEST.R` is the same file each time, you could hard-code the md5sum then compare the R script prior to running `srun Rscript   TEST.R`. This is a bit annoying to modify every time `TEST.R` changes.

Comment: If you can't create a reproducible example and things only happen "randomly" then it's probably not a code issue and more of a run-time environment issue. You should contact your network administrator for help with this one.

Comment: @MrFlick I contacted the network administrator but we couldn't figure it out. The file is the same, also because a couple of time, to test the problem, i launched the file 3 times in one minute, and the problem happened on the second. I edited the question with an example of the  slurm*.out file

Comment: Is the behaviour identical if you remove the `srun` command?

Comment: @damienfrancois yes

Comment: Are-you modifying the `TEST.R` with `vim` or `emacs` on the submission node while the job is running on a compute node?

Comment: @damienfrancois I'm using sublime text 3. Yes, sometimes it happens that I modify the file while the job is running. But I don't think i did it all the time that my problem occurs (and I'm quite sure that happens also when i don't modify the file). I may do some test.

Comment: This could potentially be a cause, depending on the exact behaviour of Sublime and of the NFS client on the nodes.

Comment: @damienfrancois It seems you may be right. I did some test and when I change the file I got the error. 
If you are willing to write an answer, with maybe a little bit more details, I can accept it so that It remains for future reference.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symptom described here, a file stored on an NFS server is corrupt when read, is most of the time associated with race conditions on the file. Typically the file is open for writing from one NFS client (the login node) and open for reading from another client (a compute node). As there is no global lock mechanism in NFS, the client that is reading the file does not know that the file is being written. With advanced editors that support auto-save, the file can sometimes be written on disk in an inconsistant state, for instance in the middle of a copy/paste operation.

One option in that scenario is to avoid modifying the file at all while jobs are submitted or at least to deactivate auto-save.

Another option is to make a copy of the file before the job is submitted so that it is not updated afterwards.